# What are the brackets in constructor in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
@immutable
abstract class MyGithubReposState extends Equatable {
  MyGithubReposState([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}
```

I have seen above code in one of the libraries I use. What does the `[List props = const []]` mean? List of list of props?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is optional parameter as explained below.

- A function can have two types of parameters:
  **required** and **optional**.

The required parameters are listed first, followed by any optional parameters. Optional parameters can be named or positional.

- Optional parameters can be either named or positional, but not both.

**Named parameters**

When calling a function, you can specify named parameters using paramName: value. For example:

> this is calling of function

```
enableFlags(bold: true, hidden: false);
```

When defining a function, use {param1, param2, …} to specify named parameters:

> this is how we define them

```
/// Sets the [bold] and [hidden] flags ...
void enableFlags({bool bold, bool hidden}) {...}
```

**Positional parameters**

Wrapping a set of function parameters in [] marks them as optional positional parameters:

```
String say(String from, String msg, [String device]) {
  var result = '$from says $msg';
  if (device != null) {
    result = '$result with a $device';
  }
  return result;
}
```

> so that we can call this function by two way

**Without optional positional parameter**

```
say('Bob', 'Howdy')
```

**With optional positional parameter**

```
say('Bob', 'Howdy', 'smoke signal')
```

[Reference here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

`[within this is optional]` means these parameters are optional

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters),

> Wrapping a set of function parameters in [] marks them as **optional positional** parameters

```
String say(String from, String msg, [String device]) {
  var result = '$from says $msg';
  if (device != null) {
    result = '$result with a $device';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here’s an example of calling this function without the optional parameter:

```
assert(say('Bob', 'Howdy') == 'Bob says Howdy');
```

And here’s an example of calling this function with the third parameter:

```
assert(say('Bob', 'Howdy', 'smoke signal') ==
    'Bob says Howdy with a smoke signal');
```